# How to direct to another page when spinner value matches with that spinner value in sqlite database?

Tags: java, mysql

On match of the spinner value i need to get directed to another page but i am getting error.

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT *FROM " + DataBaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DataBaseHelper.COL_2 + "=? AND " + DataBaseHelper.COL_4 + "=?  AND " +DataBaseHelper.COL_5 + "=?" , new String[]{uname,pass,Spinnerv1});
```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: I am getting login error.....i am not able retrieve the spinner value from the database